# D3 - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'text' of undefined

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to plot all major events in the last 30 years in US history. Here is code snippet -

```
var mevent = svg.append("text")
    .attr("class", "year event")
    .attr("text-anchor", "end")
    .attr("y", height - 450)
    .attr("x", width - 300)
    .text("mevent");

var mevents = 
    {"1987":[""],
    "1988":["Pan Am Flight 103", "US President Election"],
    "1989":["Cyclone in NE", "Bay Area Earth Quake"],
    "1990":["Tornado in MW", "Gulf War 1"],
    "1991":["Rodney King LA"],
    "1992":["Cyclone in SE", "US President Election"],
    "1993":["Great Flood of 1993 in MidWest", "Blizzard in NorthEast"],
    "1994":["Earthquake in LA"],
    "1995":["Flood in SouthEast", "Heat Wave in MidWest", "OJ Simpson Trial"],
    "1996":["Summer Olympics in Atlanta", "US President Election"],
    "1997":["Flood in MidWest", "Death of Princess Diana"],
    "1998":["Blizzard Ice Storm in NorthEast"],
    "1999":["Landslide in WA", "66 Tornadoes across MidWest and South", "Heat Wave in MidWest and NorthEast"],
    "2000":["Dot com bubble burst", "US President Election and Florida Recount"],
    "2001":["Cyclone in South", "9/11"],
    "2002":["US Invasion of Afganistan", "Winter Olympics in Salt Lake City, Utha", "US Airways Bankruptcy", "United Airlines Bankruptcy"],
    "2003":["Gulf War 2", "United Airlines Bankruptcy"],
    "2004":["Cyclones across TX, FL and East Coast",  "US President Election", "Asia Tsunami"],
    "2005":["7 Tornadoes across MidWest, South and SouthEast", "Death of Pope John Paul 2", "Hurrican Katrina"],
    "2006":["United Airlines comes out of Bankruptcy"],
    "2007":["Wildfires in CA"],
    "2008":["Tornados across South", "Lehman Brothers", "US President Election", "Mumbai Terror Attacks"]};
```

---

```
console.log(mevents[year]);     
event.text(typeof mevents[year] + " " + mevents[year]);
```

I can print the values in the console. But I cannot assign them to a text variable. What am I missing?

Comment: The typeError says .text("mevent") is not valid. What are you trying to do with .text("mevent"). If you take out .text("mevent") i think you should be able to write to console.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `svg` only contains one node, you're actually only appending a single `text` element (with the string value "mevent").

It sounds like what you want is to do a data join that will result in a `text` node for every element in the data array.

```
var mevent = svg.selectAll("text")
    .data(mevents)
    .enter().append("text")
        .attr("class", "year event")
        .attr("text-anchor", "end")
        .attr("y", height - 450)
        .attr("x", width - 300)
        .text("mevent");
```

You can learn more about this by reading the [Thinking With Joins](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/) tutorial.  This is a really fundamental part of using d3 so it's worth investing some time in really understanding how it works.